# Can you (inside of a python script) queue another script to run after the complete exit of the first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I know there are plenty of "how to run a script from inside another script" answers, but I cannot seem to find how to queue one to start after the complete termination of the first. All of the variables need to be freed and the files closed and script dead before the second runs (or if it starts running within the live parent it needs to persist after the termination of the parent because that is when the file is accessible.)

I know it would be easier to not do this but I would like to know how.

I saw wait and polling suggested on other similar-ish questions but am new to either and not sure how they fit with my specific issue.

addition: Basically I need a parent script to spawn a child that lives on after the parent terminates/dies. But I cannot kill the parent myself or switch to the child. it has to end natrually as there are some more moving parts. Otherwise the below answer would be great!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking to do is to replace the running process with a new process, which is exactly what [`os.execl`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.execl) and the set of similar functions (`os.execv`, etc.) do.

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly more than is needed, but you might be able to use `atexit`:

```
import atexit
import signal
import time
from subprocess import check_output

def last_thing(*args, **kwargs):
    def run_subprocess(*sig_args, **sig_kwargs):
        print(sig_args, sig_kwargs)
        print(check_output(['echo'] + list(args) + [k + v for k,v in kwargs.items()]))
    return run_subprocess

def main_stuff():
    atexit.register(last_thing('1', hello='world'))
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, last_thing('2', hello='world'))
    time.sleep(2)

main_stuff()
```

just a normal run of the script after 2 seconds:

```
03:51:30 (venv_ok) jmunsch@pop-os ±|PM-1371-jm-4 ✗|→ python test.py
() {}
b'1 helloworld\n'
```

exiting the script early by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> before the 2 seconds is up:

```
03:51:37 (venv_ok) jmunsch@pop-os ±|PM-1371-jm-4 ✗|→ python test.py
^C(2, <frame object at 0x1483e98>) {}
b'2 helloworld\n'
() {}
b'1 helloworld\n'
```